# Couldn't access state in vuex 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using vuex v4 with composition api. The problem is I couldn't access store states in components but I can see them in vue-devtools. When I wanna access store state it gave me `undefined`.

**store/index.ts**:

```
import { InjectionKey } from "vue";
import {
  createStore,
  createLogger,
  Store,
  useStore as vuexUseStore,
} from "vuex";
import { ConfigStateType } from "./config/state";
import config from "./config";

export enum ModuleTypes {
  CONFIG = "CONFIG",
}

export interface StateInterface {
  config: ConfigStateType;
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<StateInterface>> = Symbol();

export const store = createStore<StateInterface>({
  modules: {
    [ModuleTypes.CONFIG]: config,
  },
  strict: debug,
});

export function useStore() {
  return vuexUseStore(key);
}
```

vue js **main.ts**:

```
import { store, key } from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store, key).use(router).mount("#app");
```

In my component:

```
import { useStore } from "@/store";

setup() {
    const store = useStore();

   const recaptchaSiteKey = computed(
      () => store.state.config.googlerecaptcha_site_key
    );

return {
recaptchaSiteKey
}
}
```

always **recaptchaSiteKey** returns undefined, but in vue-devtools states are filled.

vuex devtool:
[image]

Comment: You don't call `useStore()` in your code example and assign it to `store`, eg. `const store = useStore()`

Comment: @Thomas I forgot to add it in here. it doesn't working

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's not shown how recaptchaSiteKey is used, or how googlerecaptcha_site_key is assigned. That it can be seen in devtools means that it's assigned some time in future.

Comment: @EstusFlask screenshot added. I mean vuex devtool shows that states are filled but when I wanna access it in components it returns undefined.

Comment: The screenshot is not enough. As I said, it may be defined at some time. This doesn't mean it's defined at the time when you use it.

Comment: @EstusFlask in store.subscribe i can access mutation payload.

Comment: @EstusFlask recaptchaSiteKey is just a simple state.

Comment: It's unknown at which time this happens. Please, provide MCVE, it's required by SO rules. Currently you're the only person who can reproduce and debug your case.